# What is the definition of "Augmentation Ideal Filtration"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, algebraic-topology, definition

Let $A$ be an algebra. What is the definition of the Augmentation Ideal Filtration of $A$? Any answer with reference will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $A$ is probably defined over some base ring $k$ and equipped with an 'augmentation' homomorphism $\varepsilon: A\to k$. If $A_+ := \ker(\varepsilon)$ denotes its kernel, the filtration that's meant is probably $(A_+^i)_{i\in{\mathbb N}}$. An example would be the case where $A=\bigoplus_{n\geq 0} A_n$ is non-negatively graded, $k = A_0$ and $\varepsilon: A\to k$ is the projection. Then $A_+=\bigoplus_{n>0} A_n$, $(A_+^i)_i$ is a subfiltration of the grading filtration $(A_i)_i$, and the two are equal if $A$ is generated by its degree $1$ part.

Comment: I made a mistake, the grading filtration is of course $(A_{\geq i})_i$ and not $(A_i)_i$. Then $A_+^i\subseteq A_{\geq i}$ since $A_+ = A_{\geq 1}$ and $A_i\cdot A_j\subset A_{i+j}$.

Comment: @Hanno Danke für die Antwort! Just to ask one more question: If $f:A\to A$ is a homomorphism of algebra, is it always true that $f(A_+^i)\subseteq A_+^i$?

Comment: Gerne! For the augmentation ideal filtration to be preserved you need your given homomorphism to commute with the augmentation, i.e. $\varepsilon\circ f = \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, a unital $k$-algebra is called "augmented" if it is equipped with an "augmentation", that is a $k$-algebra morphism $\epsilon : A \to k$. Then the augmentation ideal is $A_+ = \operatorname{ker}(\epsilon)$, and $A \cong A_+ \oplus k 1$ where $1$ is the unit of the algebra. The induced filtration is given (as Hanno says in the comments) by $F_i A = (A_+)^i$ (this is the ideal multiplication); then $A = F_0 A \supset F_1 A \supset \dots$ is a filtration of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! Is there any reference to this topic so that I can read more about it (introductory level preferred)? Now I am reading On the associated graded ring of a group ring by Danel G. Quillen but am not sure if it is the best one to start with.